# Django Built-in Login System - accounts/profile/ not found

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-forms

I am using django built-in login system for my website. Whenever I create an account and try to login, it redirects to the page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/` and gives error page not found.

But when I manually remove the `accounts/profile/` part from url, it logins into the website. How can I make my django system to directly redirect to `http://127.0.0.1:8000` rather than the above mentioned URL.

Here is my urls.py file code:

```
urlpatterns = [   
    path('',include('feedback.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': 'login'}, name='logout'),
    path('signup/', core_views.signup, name='signup'),
```

]

feedback/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('create_url/',views.create_url,name='create_url'),
    path('submit_affective/',views.submit_affective,name='submit_affective'),
    path('submit_cognitive/',views.submit_cognitive,name='submit_cognitive'),
    path('thanks/',views.thanks,name='thanks'),
    path('detail_affective/<int:id>',views.detail_affective,name='detail_affective'),
    path('detail_cognitive/<int:id>',views.detail_cognitive,name='detail_cognitive'),
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
```

]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The solution you are looking for is in settings.py.

By default after login django redirects the user to an accounts/profile page. If you want to redirect to a different place you need to edit the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL. Doing that you can send the user to a different page

[Here is the documentation for that setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth)

Answer (score -1):

(app/urls.py)->   From django.contrib.auth.views import login

(app/urls.py)->path('login/' login ,{'template_name':'login.html/'}),

t go settings.py and  write LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/'

make login.html in template folder

in login html make form